# Given $\mu$ the counting measure on an infinite set $\Omega$, $\lim \mu(A_n) \ne 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

**Problem:** Let $\mu$ be the counting measure on an infinite set $\Omega$.  Prove that there is a sequence of sets $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \dots$ such that $\bigcap A_n = \varnothing$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n) \ne 0$.

**Attempt**:Choose a countably infinite set $\{x_i : i \in \mathbb{N} \}  = A_1 \subseteq \Omega$.   Define $A_n = \{x_i : i \ge n\}$  Then we have $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \dots$ with $\bigcap A_n = \varnothing$.
However, $\mu(A_n) = \infty$ for all $n$.

Does my proof look correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Finding a countable subset requires (part of) AC, but that is an issue only in a set theory course.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How can one prove that $\cap A_n = \emptyset$? It is not obvious to me.